# checking a checkbox in javascript using a json value in mvc.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I bound a check box to a model like this.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ReportSchedule.Monday, new {id="boolmonday" ,name = "boolmonday",@class="dayChkbox", disabled = "disabled" })<label>Monday</label><br />
```

Now I call a JavaScript method:

```
$.get((URI.settings.getReportSchedule + '?scheduleId=' + id), function (data, status) {
    document.getElementById("boolmonday").checked = data.monday;
});
```

the function is success fully done and retrieve the json object. I have checked using a alert. The state is success and it retrieve the data. At the model data is like this.

```
var data = new
{
    reportSchedulType =repeatschedule.ReportSchedulType,
    monday=true,
    tuesday = false,
    wednesday =true,
    thursday = false,
    friday=true,
};

return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But the checkbox is not updating.

Comment: I believe you can't override the `id` when using CheckBoxFor. Check the actual rendered checkbox.

Comment: No at the html source, it shows id=boolmonday. That means it is overridden as i think.

Comment: i have solved it how ever. the java script code is given below as the answer. i am using jquery 1.6+.

Comment: -1 because you didn't include the most important info, you got an error when used .prop. and anyway, the code you "fixed" wasn't in your question at all! and you didn't even add the jQuery tag! ARGGGHH!

Comment: I was a bit off with my comment regarding `prop`, but still. there is no explanation of what was the problem and how was it fixed. I downvote and added a comment so you could fix it not to open a war. If you fix it, I'll be more than happy to revert the downvote(if the post will be helpful for future visitors a thing that is missing at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.get((URI.settings.getReportSchedule + '?scheduleId=' + id), function (data, status) {
    document.getElementById("boolmonday").checked = data.monday == 'True' ? true : false;
});
```

Comment: Can you debug the java-script and let us know what is the value in `data.monday`?

Comment: data.monday=true. I debugged it and used alert. It gives data.monday = true.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem . I am using jquery 1.6+.

```
    $.get((URI.settings.getReportSchedule + '?scheduleId=' + id), function (data, success) {
        data.monday === true ? $("#ReportSchedule_Monday").prop('checked', true) : $("#ReportSchedule_Monday").prop('checked', false);
    });
```

people who are using jquery below 1.6 should use

```
   $("#ReportSchedule_Monday").attr('checked', 'checked')
```

instead of .prop as it is not working for those versions.